# tag <a> get next hidden field

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, hidden

I have the following markup

```
  <td>
       <a id="lbtnDelete" onclick="deleteFile(this); return false;" runat="server" class="silverbutton smallbutton normal">
            <span class="left">
                  <span class="right">Delete</span>
            </span>
       </a>
       <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidDownloadId" />
  </td>

function deleteFile(element)
{
    var currEl = element;
    var downloadId = currEl.next().value;
}
```

When user clicks "lbtnDelete" link I call deleteFile(this) function. In this function I should get the value of the hidden input - hidDownloadId. How can I do it? I've already tried

```
currEl.next().value;
```

but in Chrome i got an error like "Object doesn't have method next()". Enother attempt was to do

```
currEl.parent().find('[type=hidden]')
[Exception: TypeError: Object has no method 'parent']
```

Any help would be greatly apprecitated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create jquery object out of your element before you can use jquery methods on it..

```
var currEl = $(element);
var downloadId = currEl.next().val();
```

---

But since you go the jquery way, you should also stop using inline event attributes and use jquery for the binding as well..

So

```
  <td>
       <a id="lbtnDelete" runat="server" class="silverbutton smallbutton normal">
            <span class="left">
                  <span class="right">Delete</span>
            </span>
       </a>
       <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hidDownloadId" />
  </td>
```

and

```
$(function(){
    $('#lbtnDelete').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var currEl = $(this),
            downloadId = currEl.next().val();

        // do whatever you want to do with downloadId here

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
function deleteFile(element)
{
    var currEl = $(element);
    var downloadId = currEl.next().val();
}
```

`.next()` and `.parent()` are jQuery methods and val() is the jQuery equivalent to .value